# Fluent NHibernate mapping one-to-many

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Hello i got problem with my mappings using fluent nhibernate:

```
     public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ProductID);
        Map(x => x.ProductName);
        Map(x => x.QuantityPerUnit);
        Map(x => x.ReorderLevel);
        Map(x => x.SupplierID);
        Map(x => x.UnitPrice);
        Map(x => x.UnitsInStock);
        Map(x => x.UnitsOnOrder);
        Map(x => x.CategoryID);
        Map(x => x.Discontinued);
        References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryID");
        References(x => x.Supplier).Column("SupplierID");
        Table("dbo.Products");
    }

    public SupplierMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.SupplierID);
        Map(x => x.Address);
        Map(x => x.City);
        Map(x => x.CompanyName);
        Map(x => x.ContactName);
        Map(x => x.ContactTitle);
        Map(x => x.Country);
        Map(x => x.Fax);
        Map(x => x.HomePage);
        Map(x => x.Phone);
        Map(x => x.PostalCode);
        Map(x => x.Region);
        HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .KeyColumn("SupplierID")
                       .Inverse()
                      .Cascade.All();
        Table("dbo.Suppliers");
    }

     public CategoryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.CategoryID);
        Map(x => x.CategoryName);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Picture);
        HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .KeyColumn("CategoryID")
                     .Inverse()
                    .Cascade.All();
        Table("dbo.Categories");
    }
```

when i try to do:

```
    var sessionFactory = SessionFactory.CreateSessionFactory();
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            Product fresh = new Product()
                                {
                                    ProductName = "AddFromNhibernate",
                                    SupplierID = 3,
                                    CategoryID = 5,
                                    QuantityPerUnit = "1kg pcg",
                                    UnitPrice = (decimal) 35,
                                     UnitsInStock = (short?) 15,
                                    UnitsOnOrder = 0,
                                    ReorderLevel = null,
                                    Discontinued = true
                                };
            using (session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                session.Save(fresh);
                session.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

I got System.IndexOutOfRangeException.
Whats wrong with my mappings?The work ok when i try to get some data, but adding fails. I trierd to specyfie Propertyreference for Reference in ProductMap but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you mapped some **columns** twice.

Take `ProductMap` as an example:

```
public ProductMap()
{
    (...)
    Map(x => x.SupplierID);
    (...)
    Map(x => x.CategoryID);
    References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryID");
    References(x => x.Supplier).Column("SupplierID");
    (...)
}
```

In this case, if you want to preserve the original ID **and** the reference (since they map to the same column in the database table), you should bypass the Insert/Update in one of them.

What I mean is:

```
public ProductMap()
{
    (...)
    Map(x => x.SupplierID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    (...)
    Map(x => x.CategoryID).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    References(x => x.Category).Column("CategoryID");
    References(x => x.Supplier).Column("SupplierID");
    (...)
}
```

If you dot not do so, you might get the `Exception` you described when NHibernate starts to set the insert/update parameters.

Comment: thx, it works now. But i got question: when i do that i have to create Category and Supplier object for Product and cannot simply set their id's from code. Is there possibility that would work both ways? I set CategoryId and SupplierID or i set Category object and Supplier object?

Comment: I think your doubt would be suitable for another post (question) :)